# GAE datastore performs normally in dev_server, not in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bottle

With dev_server everthin works normally. Values are saved and retrieved from the datastore. In production, nothing can be retrieved. In the traces in the dashboard, I can see the queries were run, but nothing was returned. There are no errors in the logs.

```
application: my-bottle-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: board.app
```

bottle.py:

```
class Scores(db.Model):
    player_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    score = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    score_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)


@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/home/cameron/Projects/Wordster/static')

@post('/')
def enter_score():
    data = request.json
    name = data['name']
    score = data['score']

    s = Scores(player_name=name,
              score=score)

    s.put()

@get('/')
def page():
    letters = scorer.get_letter_set()

    q = db.GqlQuery('SELECT player_name,score FROM Scores order by score DESC').fetch(5)

    return template('board', letters=letters, scores=q, letterset=json.dumps(letters))

@get('/scores')
def scores_view():
    q = db.GqlQuery('SELECT player_name,score FROM Scores order by score DESC').fetch(100)

    return template('scores', data=q)

run(server='gae')

app=default_app()
```

Comment: eventual consistency on prod? do you see the data in your datastore admin?

Comment: It just asks me to create an entity. It doesn't look like there's anything there

Comment: ok.... then did you put anything in? If you only put on dev then upload, the data you put on dev won't follow

Comment: I added data through the app. They're scores for a game. When i play the game, no scores are added

Comment: Then the problem isn't with your get I'd say, but with your put.... use some logging around it and try to figure out? Anything in your logs? Because if you say you called "enter_score" but the datastore admin is empty.... then yeah, the put doesn't work

Comment: Is there any reason a put would work in dev_server and not in production?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Hence why I think logs might be your best bet here. log something in your "enter_score" method and see if it's reflected

Comment: You should insert the values using an ancestor, this will assure you that your data are going to be available at any time.

Comment: @RenatoReyes Ancestors are not a be all answer. They have other limitation. Since OP is going to the datastore admin, consistency should not be a problem (the admin is ALWAYS strongly consistent), and if you want consistency without ancestors (to bypass the entity groups limitations), you can always do get by keys :)

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple stupid problem, thanks to Patrice for helping narrow it down. All I did was forget to change the url in my javascript callback function handling the post request.

Comment: Happy I was of help ^^. Happy coding on the platform :)